# Android - Project use Kotlin but Firebase Crashlytics is Java

Tags: android, firebase-crash-reporting

My project use Kotlin, and I use Firebase Crashlytics latest version, but crashlytics for flavor `pro` show Java code of crash.

product flavors

```
productFlavors {
    pro {
        applicationId 'xxx'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.pro
    }
    dev {
        applicationId 'xxx.dev'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.dev
    }
}
```

Flavor `pro` for Production (has Proguard) and `dev` for Developement

How to fix it?

Many thanks.

[image: Crashlytics Pro]

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57575898/14759470

Comment: Thank you, so that is problem of Firebase Crashlytics.